# How does one remove a curse and/or a magical spell that's been placed upon a person/land/lineage/etc? What is the process like?

Tags: tanach, mysticism-kabbalah, health-safety-shmira, sorcery-magic-kishuf, curse

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in סימן קסו - שלא לנחש לעונן ולכשף says that one can go to a non-Jew if they are suffering from an ailment caused by magic, which means that there must be a way to rid oneself of negative impacts of magic. Some argue that a curse is a potentially a form of magic (perhaps depending on how its done).

Based on this, what is the process of removing a curse or a magical spell that's been thrown on someone? I'm interested in what exact rituals, incantations, etc. is one supposed to use in such a scenario? Is it possibly to simply pray and it will get removed? Does the type of magical spell or curse being used affect the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1). See Nefesh Hachaim (3:12) that Rebbi Chanina was not affected by witchcraft and was not scared (even as a witch gathered dust beneath his feet to cast a spell) because he believed and knew that there is only one power, Hashem. He clung to Hashem and so nothing else could affect him. The Nefesh Hachaim writes this is a great thing to save one's self from judgements and designs of others.

> ובאמת הוא ענין גדול וסגולה נפלאה להסר ולבטל מעליו כל דינין ורצונות
> אחרים שלא יוכלו לשלוט בו ולא יעשו שום רושם כלל, כשהאדם קובע בלבו לאמר,
> הלא ה' הוא האלקים האמיתי, ואין עוד מלבדו יתברך שום כח בעולם...

Personally, I consider the most practical and beneficial as it causes one to be a greater person and connect to Hashem.

2). In the Sefer "Divrei Torah" (ח׳׳ו סי׳ נ׳׳ו) he states that the Rambam held that one who doesn't believe in Kishuf it has no affect on him. Similar to #1 but not the same. He surmises that this is why the Rambam says witchcraft is not real. So his followers in Egypt (the heart of witchcraft) would not be affected even though perhaps the Rambam knew it was real. I am sure many would disagree with this part, but many times we find if you do not believe in something it has no effect: demons, evil eye etc...

3). See Taamei HaMinhagim (likut 128) that water will undo or remove any magical effect (see Rashi Sanhedrin 67: That he connected it to water and it turned into a tree since it was only through magic and is nullified with water). Perhaps this means River water or even Ocean water.

Similarly Ahavat Yonatan mentions the ability of פשתן to stop witchcraft (see הפטרת שלח לך).

4). Sefer Chassidim says מי שמכושף אין לו תקנה אלא שיצא מן העיר וידור בעיר אחרת, ויקח בעיר אחרת אשה... (תצח)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any authoritarian source other than what I heard from parents and grandparents of the generations before me.  In that light, and this is not Torah miMoshe beSinai, let me pass on the following:  If the 'curse' is an ayin hara (evil eye), the person to go to for a 'cure' is a bechor (first born male).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for sharing this knowledge!